# Bind to scope from nested resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am always running into this issue where I am trying to bind to scope from a nested resolve function ( `.then()` ) because I'd like to refresh the view with the updated data from the database.

However, inside the nested resolve, I can never bind to the scope for some reason. This doesn't make sense to me as it works fine from the first resolve.

Although there is a simple yet tedious workaround for this by storing the data from the second resolve into a service and then use a watcher in the controller to check if the service changes and then update the scope, it feels like overkill for such a simple thing.

Surely the must be a more clean and simple way of binding to the scope from a nested resolve function?

Example api calls with resolves:

```
// Simple $http.get requests from my factory which gets resolved here
tagApi.delete({id: item.id}).then(function(res) {

    // Binding scope from here works
    $scope.someProp = res;

    tagApi.edit({id: res.id}).then(function(res) {

        // But not from inside here
        $scope.someProp = res;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
tagApi.delete({id: item.id})
.then(function(res) {

    // Binding scope from here works
    $scope.someProp = res;

    return tagApi.edit({id: res.id});
})
.then(function(result) {
  $scope.someProp = result;
})
```

Comment: Completely forgot that one resolve can pass on data to another resolve, brilliant! Works so good :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$broadcast` in the success function of tagApi.delete:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('tag:deleted', res);
```

Then:

```
$rootScope.$on('tag:deleted', editFunc);
var editFunc = function (event, res) {
  tagApi.edit({id: res.id});
};
```